Is there a hook to modify field value in Django?
On any type of Django Field, validators is available where I can hook my own custom validator. I understand I cannot change the value in the validator, it must either return None or django.core.exceptions.ValidationError.
What I want to do is I want to change the value of the field itself, before it gets saved. For example, I want to store ISO 3166 Numeric Code as a column:
def digit_only(value):
    if not value.isdigit():
        raise ValidationError(
            _("%(value)s contains a non-digit"),
            params={"value": value},
        )

class Country(models.Model):
   # ...
   iso3166_numeric = models.CharField(max_length=3, validators=[digit_only])
   # ...

So far, so good. Now, if the value input is '1', I want to convert it to '001' before the value is stored on the table. Without creating a new Field type and then writing custom Field.to_python(), can I achieve the same, as simply as using validators?
I am still learning, and I have not reached as far as Forms yet, but I am trying to achieve the above when seeding from a CSV through Djano command. Yes, I could modify the value immediately on reading from CSV, but I am trying to find out if there is one single place where I can do this so that I don't have to write it separately for Forms as well.

You typically do the cleaning in the form, not the model.

Why not create a subclass? It is not that hard, and you can include validation, wrap it in objects, etc.

This is called cleaning, and Django does not allow hooking in "cleaners" in the Model itself, or at least not easily. You can clean on the level that process input with clean_fieldname() on the Forms, validate_fieldname() in a serializer, etc.
You could override the .save() method [Django-doc], but these do not run for bulk creates for example.
I therefore would advise to just do this with a custom field, like:
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Iso3166NumericField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 3)
        validators = kwargs.setdefault('validators', [])
        validators.append(RegexValidator('^\\d{,3}$'))
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is not None:
            value = value.zfill(3)
        return super().to_python(value)


class Country(models.Model):
    # …
    iso3166_numeric = Iso3166NumericField()

Thank you. I believe I can make a generic DigitCharField, and use zfill and validation length same as max_length. In general, I should be able to add more custom parms in the __init__ too for other use-cases. I have one more observation from my tests: the validations don't run when I execute Model.objects.create(). Do validations run only for forms?

@fishfin: yes, Model.objects.create(..) does not even run the validators. Only ModelForms, and ModelSerializers (and all sorts of things derive from the model) do. You can indeed use .max_length as parameter for .zfill(..) thus generalizing it to for any number of digits.

Default Model.objects.create() and Model.save() don't call Model.full_clean() which in turn calls Model.clean_fields() (then Field.to_python(), Field.validate() and Field.run_validators() for validator hooks), then Model.clean(), then Model.validate_unique() and Model.validate_constraints().  I don't want to call full_clean() in save(), as I want it to be that if a save is called, all values can be saved as-is. Using management command, is the best place to call full_clean() immediately after instantiating my Model from csv row, and if it passes, call save()?

Side question: if there is a Model.save(), why does there exist Model.objects.create() via ModelManager?

@fishfin: .create(..) calls .save() with force_create=True, so slightly boosting efficiency, as for the .save(), you can call .full_clean() in the .save() method, but again, .bulk_create(..) which is usually what one does when creating a lot of recods,does not call .full_clean() or any other cleaning/validating. Probably django-import-export does, or has some tooling to first call .full_clean() and then perhaps bulk create, or create one-by-one.
